# How can I prevent the temporary loading of a placeholder image in this Vue 3 app?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs3

I have been working on an SPA with **Vue 3**, **TypeScript** and **The Movie Database (TMDB) API**.

I want to display the movie poster on the movie details page if there is a poster, otherwise I want to display a placeholder (generic-poster-big.png).

For this purpose, in `src\components\MovieDetails.vue`, I have:

```
<template>
  <div class="poster-container text-center text-sm-start my-3">
    <img
      :src="genericPoster"
      :alt="movie?.title"
      class="img-fluid shadow-sm"
    />
  </div>
</template>

<script lang="ts">
import { defineComponent } from "vue";
import { useRoute } from "vue-router";
import axios from "axios";
import env from "../env";
import { Movie } from "../models/Movie";

export default defineComponent({
  name: "MovieDetails",

  data() {
    return {
      route: useRoute(),
      genericPosterBig: require("../assets/generic-poster-big.png"),
      movie: null as Movie | null
    };
  },

  mounted() {
    this.getMovieDetails();
  },

  methods: {
    getMovieDetails() {
      axios
        .get(
          `${env.api_url}/movie/${this.route.params.id}?api_key=${env.api_key}`
        )
        .then((response) => {
          this.movie = response.data;
        })
        .catch((err) => console.log(err));
    },

  computed: {
    genericPoster() {
      return !this.movie?.poster_path
        ? this.genericPosterBig
        : `https://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w500/${this.movie?.poster_path}`;
    },
  }
});
</script>
```

#### The problem

When there is a movie poster, *before it loads*, the generic poster appears, for a fraction of a second, yet visible.

#### Questions

1. What am I doing wrong?
2. What is the most reliable way to fix this problem?

Comment: You should only load the generic poster if the image fail to load or if you don't have an url for that movie, and put a loader before the image url is available. Put a `v-if="movie"` on your img tag, and put a loader instead on the `v-else`. Then load your image, or your generic poster if you don't have any image url but you do have a movie. You could add an `@error` listener on top of that to put the generic poster in the img, in case of an error with your movie poster.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Something like the following should do the trick, added lines marked with `**********`

```
<template>
  <div class="poster-container text-center text-sm-start my-3">
    <!-- ************ -->
    <img v-if="loaded"
      :src="genericPoster"
      :alt="movie?.title"
      class="img-fluid shadow-sm"
    />
  </div>
</template>

<script lang="ts">
import { defineComponent } from "vue";
import { useRoute } from "vue-router";
import axios from "axios";
import env from "../env";
import { Movie } from "../models/Movie";

export default defineComponent({
  name: "MovieDetails",

  data() {
    return {
      //************************
      loaded: false, 
      route: useRoute(),
      genericPosterBig: require("../assets/generic-poster-big.png"),
      movie: null as Movie | null
    };
  },

  mounted() {
    this.getMovieDetails();
  },

  methods: {
    getMovieDetails() {
      axios
        .get(
          `${env.api_url}/movie/${this.route.params.id}?api_key=${env.api_key}`
        )
        .then((response) => {
          this.movie = response.data;
        })
        .catch((err) => console.log(err))
        //****************
        .finally(() => this.loaded = true); 
    },

  computed: {
    genericPoster() {
      return !this.movie?.poster_path
        ? this.genericPosterBig
        : `https://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w500/${this.movie?.poster_path}`;
    },
  }
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

This behaviour is expected given your solution, but I understand you want to improve this for UX reasons.

The problem is that your component is mounted before the data is available, so you need to set a logic on what to do while it's loading

I see two solutions for this:

1. Set your placeholder image only in case the main image fails to load (i.e. when the url is wrong or it's empty). So it will only loads your placeholder after trying to load the main image, not before.

While it loads, use a loading spinner on your image while it's loading, not the image placeholder (which should appear only once the poster details has been fetched). This is useful to avoid layout flickering: it will reserve the space required by the image.

```html
<template>
  <div class="poster-container text-center text-sm-start my-3">
    <div v-if="loading">Loading spinner...</div>
    <img
      v-else
      :src="movie.poster_path"
      :alt="movie.title"
      class="img-fluid shadow-sm"
      @error="setPlaceholder"
    />
  </div>
</template>

<script>
{
  data() {
    return {
       movie: null,
       loading: true,
       genericPosterBig: null,
    }
  }
  mounted() {
    this.getMovieDetails()
  },
  methods: {
    getMovieDetails() {
      this.loading = true
      axios.get(`${env.api_url}/movie/${this.route.params.id}?api_key=${env.api_key}`)
        .then(({ data }) => {
          this.movie = data;
        })
        .catch((err) => console.log(err))
        .finally(() => {
          this.loading = false
        });
    },
    setPlaceholder(event) {
       // This loads the image only if it's not already assigned
       this.genericPosterBig ||= require("../assets/generic-poster-big.png")
       event.target.src = this.genericPosterBig
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

2. Using the Nuxt framework, you could preload the movies details before mounting the movie details page using the [`useAsyncData()`](https://nuxt.com/docs/api/composables/use-async-data) composable (or for [option api](https://nuxt.com/docs/api/utils/define-nuxt-component#asyncdata)), so you are sure you already have all the movies data when creating the details page (so no flickering).

```js
{
  // This will block the page rendering until the promise is settled.
  async asyncData() {
     const movieDetails = await axios
        .get(`${env.api_url}/movie/${this.route.params.id}?api_key=${env.api_key}`)
        .then((response) => response.data)
     return { movieDetails }
  }
}
```

Comment: since the "default" value of loading is `false`, would this not produce a "flash" of an empty `<img>` tag? since you also have removed the definition of `genericPoster` so what will `:src="genericPoster"` do?

Comment: I mean it's just an implementation example, not a copy-pastable solution. I updated it so that the code is more correct but you should indeed adjust a few things.

Answer (score 1):

Apparently, making sure that the *movie is loaded before trying to render the poster* at all, with `v-if`, fixed the issue:

```
 <img v-if="movie"
      :src="genericPoster"
      :alt="movie?.title"
      class="img-fluid shadow-sm"
 />
```

Comment: oh yeah, that works far better :p didn't think of using an existing data property :p